# changing property of controls via methods from another form won't affect?

Tags: c#

I'm Working with C# application. I want to change the visibility of panel container of a form from another form, like setting preference.

The problem I faced is: when I call the method which contains the visibility method of the container from another form, it is not affecting any thing.
Please help me.

This is the Main Form which contains the method :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        public void langPref_Amharic()
        {
            main_amharic_pannel.Visible = true;
            main_english_pannel.Visible = false;
            home_amharic_title.Visible = true;
            home_eng_title.Visible = false;
        }
        public void langPref_English()
        {
            main_amharic_pannel.Visible = false;
            main_english_pannel.Visible = true;
            home_amharic_title.Visible = false;
            home_eng_title.Visible = true;
        }
```

This code is from another form to Call the method and to apply the property:

```
 public partial class frm_Settings : Form
    {
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();

        public frm_Settings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (opt_amharic.Checked == true)
            {
                main.langPref_Amharic();
            }
            if (opt_english.Checked == true)
            {
                main.langPref_English();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass a *reference* to the existing window. Right now you are creating a new one (hence the `new` keyword) and not using the one you already have open. Pass the reference to `this` form to the constructor of your settings form and modify the properties of that object.

Comment: Please can you help me just by editing my code, I'm a new user for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the existing form, not a new one. The easiest way to do this is to pass a reference to the existing form in the constructor of your settings form.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Form
        {
            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }


            public void langPref_Amharic()
            {
                main_amharic_pannel.Visible = true;
                main_english_pannel.Visible = false;
                home_amharic_title.Visible = true;
                home_eng_title.Visible = false;
            }
            public void langPref_English()
            {
                main_amharic_pannel.Visible = false;
                main_english_pannel.Visible = true;
                home_amharic_title.Visible = false;
                home_eng_title.Visible = true;
            }

            public void OpenSettingsForm()
            {
                frm_Settings settings = new frm_Settings(this);
                settings.Show();
            }
    }
```

Then in your settings form, its a simple modification to the constructor to accept the reference:

```
 public partial class frm_Settings : Form
    {
        MainWindow main;

        public frm_Settings(MainWindow mainWin)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            main = mainWin;
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (opt_amharic.Checked == true)
            {
                main.langPref_Amharic();
            }
            if (opt_english.Checked == true)
            {
                main.langPref_English();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is happening here is that you were creating a new instance of the main window form. This means exactly what it sounds like, its a *new* instance. You really want to reference the existing instance so you need to pass the reference to the new form.

If you have issues with the visibility not working, you may need to modify your settings form to invoke the functions on the dispatcher, like this:

**Note, this is WPF specific**

```
if (opt_amharic.Checked == true)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { main.langPref_Amharic(); });
}
if (opt_english.Checked == true)
{
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { main.langPref_English(); });
}
```

**This one is for winforms**

```
if (opt_amharic.Checked == true)
{
    main.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { main.langPref_Amharic(); });
}
if (opt_english.Checked == true)
{
    main.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { main.langPref_English(); });
}
```

Which verifies that the updates happen on the UI thread, which is required by UI applications.